# Create windows of results per alphabet

Tags: xquery

My XML file is [here](http://expirebox.com/download/3eb64bcb5a820ad8012ce65ca59d60e3.html).

I would like to get the results of all movie titles by alphabet in the following manner:

```
<window>
<title>Alpha</title>
<title>Abel</title>
<window>
<title><babylon</title>
...
<window>
...
<window>
...
```

I am using tumbling feature in the following code:

```
for tumbling window $w in db:open("movies","movies.xml")/movies/movie/title
    start at $s when fn:true()
    only end at $e when not starts-with($e,substring($s, 1, 1))
return <window>{ $w/../title }</window>
```

Basically, I am trying to extract first character of each words and grouping them together.

However, It says incomplete FLWOR expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group by would be more appropriate here:

```
for $title in //title
  order by $title
  group by $g := substring($title, 1,1)
return element { $g } {
  $title
}
```

when you really want to use tumbling you could use the start and next variables to create groups:

```
for tumbling window $w in //title
  start $first when true()
  end next $next when substring($first, 1,1) != substring($next,1,1)
return <window>{ $w }</window>
```

Comment: I agree. I wanted to do it using windows

Comment: It is creating separate windows per title

Comment: i couldn't access your original input file so I made something up, but it could be because your input (//title) is not ordered. You can either order it first or use the group by :)